# Problem reading the characters from vector C++

Tags: c++

I tried to write a simple code that gives all 3 chars combinations of alphabet letters, but it doesn't read the ASCII code (90) character which is 'Z' . Also why letters repeat in combinations in any 90 line?

Here is the code:

```
{
    int i, j, k;
    char v[90];

    for(i=65; i<=90; ++i)
        v[i]=(unsigned char)i;
    for(i=65; i<=90; ++i)
    {
        for(j=65; j<=90; ++j)
            if(i!=j)
            {
                for(k=65; k<=90; ++k)
                    if(j!=k && i!=k)
                        cout<< v[i] << v[j] << v[k] << ' ';
                cout<<endl;
            }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The top element of a 90-element array `v` is `v[89]`.

You can't use `v[90]`; it doesn't exist.

Either make it `char v[91]` instead, or change the way you use arrays (there's no need for so many elements here).

Comment: how can I define the array with just 65-90 positions ?

Comment: Use subtraction. e.g. 65-65=0, 90-65=25....

Answer (score 1):

`char v[90]` makes an array with 90 elements, numbered 0 through 89.  By accessing element 90 of the list, you are accessing bits of memory used by other things, and thus you can't expect what you put in there to stay there.  Initializing the array as 91 elements long should fix both problems.

Comment: "Accessing bits of memory used by other things" is just one possible outcome of this undefined behaviour

Comment: OMG... so stupid at this hour. It work great, thanks.

Comment: Can I define the vector with just 65-90 positions ?